# valueForKey returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Dumb question warning...I might be deprived of sleep, but I can't seem to figure this out.

'current' is an NSDictionary

```
if ([current valueForKey:@"name"] != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"here %@", [current valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

This prints

```
here John
here Sam
here <null>
here <null>
here Billy
```

Shouldn't the 'if xx != nil' have prevented the nulls?  'name' exists in my dictionary, but the value of name may be empty.

Comment: Have you got your solutions ?

Comment: `nil` and `null` or two completely different things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSArray` and `NSDictionary` cannot contain nil values. `NSNULL` was created specifically as a placeholder for nil. It can be put into collection classes, and only takes up space.

`NSNull` defines a singleton object, which means that there's only ever a single instance of `NSNull` but it can be used in as many places as you wish.

And you need to check like this....

```
if (current != nil || [current valueForKey:@"name"] != [NSNull null] )
{
      NSLog(@"here %@", [current valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

And i'm sure you will get this output.....

**Output**

```
here John
here Sam
here Billy
```

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be && instead of || ?  Didn't work with ||, but seems to be working with &&

Comment: What you are saying here is actually incorrect or at a minimum misleading. You can call `valueForKey` in a `NSDictionary` and get `nil` if there is no matching key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
if ([current valueForKey:@"name"] != nil | [current valueForKey:@"name"]!=[NSNull null] )
{
    NSLog(@"here %@", [current valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( [[current valueForKey:@"name"] length]!=0)
{
    NSLog(@"here %@", [current valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.